# Check if custom post is a parent?

Tags: custom-post-types, conditional-tags

I am using the following query to list all posts within the post type 'services':

```
                <?php $args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_type' => services,
                );
                $query = new WP_Query( $args );
                if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                <li class="hvr-sweep-to-left">stuff here</li>
                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

My post type is heirarchical, and I want to check if the post is a parent, if so then add a class. I tried the following:

```
global $post;
if ( $post->post_parent > 0 ) {
$class = 'haschildren';
} else {
$class = ''; }
```

But this just returned the class for all. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a little more involved than you really need - it includes the top Post (or Page or CPT) and continues on to list the full tree.

```
<?php
// Get the top page in the current tree
$ancestors = $post->ancestors;
// If this page isn't the top one in the tree
if($ancestors) {
    // The last ancestor is highest in the tree
    $topParentID = end($ancestors);
    // Use whatever class you want here to differentiate the parent
    echo '<li class="topLevel page_item"><a href="' . get_the_permalink($topParentID) . '">' . get_the_title($topParentID) . '</a>';
} else {
    $topParentID = $post->ID;
    echo '<li class="topLevel page_item hasChildren current">' . get_the_title($topParentID);
}
echo '<ul class="children">';
wp_list_pages(array(
    'post_type' => 'your_cpt',
    'child_of' => "$topParentID",
    'title_li' => '',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'sort_column' => 'post_title',
    'walker' => new childNav_walker)
);
echo '</ul></li>';
?>
```

If you aren't worried about listing the full tree, you could just use a custom walker in a wp_list_pages call similar to the one above, and your walker is what will add the class to every Post (or Page or CPT) that has at least one child.

Walker code for functions.php:

```
<?php
// childnav walker
class childNav_walker extends Walker_page {
    public function start_el(&$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_page = 0) {
        if($depth)
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        else
            $indent = '';
        extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
        $css_class = array('page_item');
        if(!empty($current_page)) {
            $_current_page = get_page( $current_page );
            $children = get_children('post_type=page&post_status=publish&post_parent='.$page->ID);
            if(count($children) != 0) {
                // this is where you add your custom CSS class,
                // change it to whatever you like.
                $css_class[] = 'hasChildren';
            }
            if(isset($_current_page->ancestors) && in_array($page->ID, (array) $_current_page->ancestors))
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_ancestor';
            if($page->ID == $current_page)
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_item';
            elseif($_current_page && $page->ID == $_current_page->post_parent)
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
        } elseif($page->ID == get_option('page_for_posts')) {
            $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
        }
        $css_class = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'page_css_class', $css_class, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page ) );
        if($page->ID == $current_page) {
            $output .= $indent .'<li class="' . $css_class . '">' . $page->post_title;
        } else {
            $output .= $indent .'<li class="' . $css_class . '"><a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . $page->post_title .'</a>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

As shown above you can use the Page walker as long as you specify your Post Type in the call.